# Proving that $l_r$ is dense everywhere in $l_p$ $1\leq r \leq p$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

$$l_p=\{(x_i)^{\infty}_{i=1}|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i|^p<\infty\}$$

The answer is given, but this proof makes no sense to me. If somebody could explain the logic, idea here, I would be very grateful.

$$\{e_i\}^{\infty}_{i=1}-\text{ this is the base of $l_r$ maybe???} \\\{e_i\}^{\infty}_{i=1} \subseteq l_r \subseteq l_p \\ span\{e_i\}^{\infty}_{i=1} \subseteq l_r \subseteq l_p \\ 
 span\{e_i\}^{\infty}_{i=1}\subseteq \overline{(l_r)_{l_p}} \subseteq l_p  \\ 
 l_p\subseteq\overline{(l_r)_{l_p}} \subseteq l_p \\ l_p=\overline{(l_r)_{l_p} } \implies \text{ $l_r$ is everywhere dense in $l_p.$}$$

I am told that $\{e_i\}^{\infty}_{i=1}$ is a fundamental set in some sense.

Comment: What is $r$ here? Is $p<\infty$?

Comment: Doesn't say that $p< \infty $ but that is possible.

Comment: @JerryWest $e_i$ is the sequence with only zeros except at place $i$, where it is $1$. That is, $e_i = (\delta_{in})_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

Comment: it contains $c_{00}$, the sequences which are finitely non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

Every $\ell^p$ space with $1\leq p\leq\infty$ contains the space $c_c(\mathbb{N})$ of sequences which are zero after finitely many terms. When $p<\infty$, $c_c(\mathbb{N})$ is a dense subset of $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$. Since it is contained in $\ell^r(\mathbb{N})$, $\ell^r$ must be dense in $\ell^p$.

The claim is not true for $p=\infty$, because the constant sequence 1 cannot be closely approximated in $\ell^{\infty}$ by elements of $\ell^r$ for $r<\infty$.

Comment: You mean the claim is **not** true for $p=\infty$. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I suppose I could have phrased that better

Comment: Can you by anychance provide a link to a proof, or if it is not too difficult, that $c_c(\mathbb N)$ is a dense subset of $l^p(\mathbb N)$?

Comment: Here's the idea: given $x\in \ell^p$ and $\varepsilon>0$, choose $N$ such that $\sum_{n>N}|x(n)|^p<\varepsilon^p$, and define $y\in c_c$ such that $y(n)=x(n)$ for $1\leq n\leq N$, $y(n)=0$ for $n>N$. Then $||y-x||_p<\varepsilon$.